# AWS SNS mutiple text contents in one message

Tags: amazon-sns

I'm looking to implement a robust desktop app notification mechanism based on the pub/sub pattern. While I'm exploring AWS SNS for this purpose, I've encountered some limitations regarding the complexity of messages that AWS SNS can handle.

To give you an idea of my requirements, I need to display notifications as small popups in the bottom right corner of users' screens. These notifications can take various forms. For example, they might include a small image, text, and a button that directs users to our website. Alternatively, they could simply consist of a URL.

Could anyone provide guidance on whether there are alternative solutions to AWS SNS that might better suit my needs? Furthermore, I'm wondering if AWS SNS is capable of sending multiple texts within a single notification, rather than being limited to a single text message at a time. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I read AWS SNS documents as well as other Internet resources I found on the Internet.